# How to make a hr stay when you scroll

Tags: html, css

Ive **tried** doing this but its not working, What im trying to say is basically, I made a a **box** that you can scroll in, Kind of like the **server bar** from **discord**, It has a **hr** so i also added it but **it follows but i want it to stay under the T logo** the **scrolling**.
https://gyazo.com/91f62e8b813380d0f80a5e3713a371d3

```
div.sidescroll {
  background-color: #202225;
  height: 96%;
  width: 4%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: auto;
}


<hr width="50px" style="border-radius: 50px; height: 3px; left: 1.0%; top: 60px; position: fixed;">
```

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow community. 
Please improve your question with your code. There is nothing we can see with this. 
Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by removing `position: fixed;left: 1.0%;top: 60px;` from `<hr>` `style`

But a easier option will be applying `border-bottom` to the element which is containing T logo and adding `border-radius/padding` according to need

Comment: You guys are my saviours, Thank you very much

Comment: Any time brother no worries

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you applied a `top` and `left` property as well as the `fixed` position. Try to remove all positional properties and it should stay as intended.

Comment: You guys are my saviours, Thank you very much

Comment: @MonkeyMan no worries mate :). Upvote maybe..? ;)